# Read field value and pass it to section style atributes only for node page

Tags: 7, entities, theming

I have a color field in content type -> page fields. And i want to read the values of this field and pass this value as a background color(bootstrap subtheme) to element  for main content ( - from page,tlp.php). And only for node type -> page.

In my template.php i tried to use function theme_preprocess_page. My code:

```
function theme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {

    if (isset($vars['node'])) {

        $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' . $vars['node']->type . 'page';

        // check the node type and specific field in not empty  
        if (($vars['node']->type = 'page') && (!empty($content['field_color']['#items'][0]['value']))) {

            //read the value of color field
            $bg_color = $content['field_color']['#items'][0]['rgb'];            

        }
    }
}
```

but i dont know how to pass the value of color field ($content['field_color']) to section style attributes. Should i use $vars['attributes_array']['style'] ? and how to pass it to section element style.

Help please.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $color = preg_replace("/#/i", "", $bg_color);  
$vars['classes_array'][] = $color;
 $vars['style'] = "style='background-color:$bg_color'";
```

Comment: Thx but how to render this for a section.

Comment: can you please elaborate what u mean by section ??

Comment: page.tpl.php element <section> in main content container -> section element in bootstrap theme.

<div class="row">
<section<?php print $content_column_class?> style="i want to render value of colo field here">
</section>
</div>

Comment: <div <?php if(!empty($style)) print $style; ?> class="<?php print $classes; ?>"></div> the color will be rendered there

Comment: it renders only <div class="page"></div>

Comment: Is the style getting applied??

Comment: Nope. It renders only div with class"page" no styles applied ( <div class="page"> </div>)

Comment: dsm ($vars ['style']) is color printin

Comment: i dont understand what you mean